# How to populate a ListView with JavaFX and SceneBuilder

Tags: java, listview, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Here is my code:

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> clientList;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    clientList = new ListView<>();
    clientList.getItems().addAll("test", "test2");
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong? It seems really simple but maybe I've misunderstood the basics..?

Thanks

Comment: If you're defining `clientList` in the FXML file, you should not be creating a new one in the `initialize()` method.

Comment: oooh thats embarrassing. Ok thanks I was following a tutorial but I should have changed it to suit my needs better, thanks :)